# App.config only read when debugging

Tags: .net, configuration-files, configuration-management

I am currently experiencing an issue that I haven't been able to resolve.

I have an application where I have this code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "App.config");
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile = Path.Combine(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "App.config");
MessageBox.Show(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Count.ToString());
```

The configuration file is indeed called App.config in the application folder (I am doing this because I have two applications reading/modifying the same config file).

When I start either of them through the Visual Studio Debugger, it correctly tells me that I have 11 appsettings. However, when run outside of the debugger, I get 0.

What might be wrong here?
I am 100% sure that this code has worked in the past.

Comment: Have you tried passing the full path to App.config instead of the relative path? Perhaps, the app.config file is not resolving correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve it myself right now. The solution is to access the configuration settings through

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not passing the correct path to App.Config. Try this instead:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", "App.config");
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "App.config"); 
MessageBox.Show(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Count.ToString());
```

Notice the call to Path.GetDirectoryName(). Your code is getting the location to the exe file, and is then appending "App.Config" to it, which is resolving to a file that does not exist.